# Daily developer "dance scrum" meeting

Tags: scrum, agile, meetings, daily-scrum

In the Harvard Business Review's Guide to Making Every Meeting Matter, one contributor describes a unique process for their daily standup:

"To keep impromptu meetings short, I instituted Dance
Meetings. By playing some funk [music] at low levels through
my computer speakers, I’d encourage my colleagues
to dance. We’d dance for the duration of the song as
we discussed their projects, challenges, personal troubles,
and so on.
The benefits were immediately clear:

• Meetings were kept to about five minutes—
maximum, 10, for an extended James Brown
tune.

• Self-conscious people were intimidated and
didn’t drop in as often.

• The dancing immediately put us in a good
mood—so much so that even people with major
complaints always left my office with a smile.
• It was a lovely, surreal bonding moment that
boosted morale within my team.

This isn’t the sort of extreme method that will work
in every office, of course, but it sure worked at my
casual-yet-hectic workplace. And it certainly made for
quick and effective meetings."

Our company currently facilitates a number of software development Scrum teams, which have been effective for a number of years (well past the forming / storming / norming stages). We're planning on expanding these teams in the near future, but we think it's a natural time for some team evolution. Does this sound like a feasible route to explore, or will it simply put our employees too far out of their comfort zones?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SEPM, habe a look on the [tour] page to see how this site works. Could you provide a reference to the article?

Comment: Currently, this question is written as a poll. With some editing, this question could certainly be made on-topic, but polls and requests for anecdotal experiences are never on topic.

Comment: surely this practice would make the standup longer? can you really dance and give an update at the same time would the other team members be listening to you or just watching you do the robot ;)

Comment: Is it April already...?  ;-)

Comment: thanks for the comments, added the reference and worded it as a question instead of a poll

Comment: "self conscious people were intimidated" - I'm very uncomfortable with praising any technique that intimidates part of your workforce. I'm even more uncomfortable that you seem to be pleased to proceed with status information that intentionally excludes/marginalizes/disenfranchizes parts of your team. (I'm not sure I can call it a "team" if intimidation is part of the work ethic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not seen this in action. What I do know is this sounds like a team evolution.

When a team is still in the forming, storming or even norming phase, comfort is still being established. At this point you are working on team cohesion and team trust. Having spent a lot of time in theatre I can tell you it takes a lot of trust for a good acting troupe to work well together.

So something like introducing dancing, which may be well outside the comfort zone of your average software engineer, is something you probably want to hold off doing until you've hit the performing stage and are looking for the next evolution of team dynamics. Get to trust first, then start experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

In truth, I never even heard about this technique of Daily Scrum before. Despite this, I think that it is very infantile practice (it's my personal opinion). I strongly believe, that in case if I will suggest implement this practice on retrospective, most censorial answer from my team will be something like "*OMG, are you serious?*". Almost all members of my team don't like game elements within development process (yes, we are boring guys), such as the lego-retrospective and others.

But! My team is my team. Your team is your team. There is no silver bullet. All teams are unique. If this technique isn't applicable to my team, it doesn't mean that this practice will be bad for your team.

But! Be careful with implementation of this practice. All of your team members should have specific psychotype for this technique. Even if there is one member of the team, which will have discomfort during dancing, I think will be better to not use this practice.